# SEARCH_ACTION doesn't work in my SearchActivity

Tags: android, search, android-activity, action

I'm trying to implement google's new feature, Search using a specific app. I want to ask something to google now in this format "search for ... on myApp" but it doesn't work.

This is the only code google recommend to add in AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

StartActivity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.actions.SearchIntents;

public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (SearchIntents.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(i.getAction())) {
        String query = i.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Toast.makeText(this, query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My app isn't signed! Could it be this the problem?

Comment: Add more code that you are using here.

Comment: I've edited @Eenvincible !!

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your code, I'd suggest reading up on [Creating a Search Interface.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html?utm_campaign=voice-search-1014&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog&utm_source=gdbc&utm_medium=blog#DeclaringSearchableActivity)

At first glance, it looks like you're missing the

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
```

after your IntentFilter.

ETA: I don't think having the Toast show in onCreate is going to give you any information. Searching will have to happen after the onCreate method. Breakpoint through your onCreate and see what the value of "i" (your Intent) is.